# Google visualization - set color

Tags: c#, google-visualization

In my application I want to show the bar chart as below
if the "Actual" value is greater than 'Planned" then the Actual bar should be red color and if less than 'Planned" then it should be in 'green' color
I have used the below code

```
stringBuilder.Append(@"<script type=*text/javascript*> google.load( *visualization*, *1*, {packages:[*corechart*]});
                                                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                                                function drawChart() {
                                                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                                                data.addColumn('string', 'ResourceName');
                                                data.addColumn('number', 'Planned');
                                                data.addColumn('number', 'Actual');


                            data.addRows(" + dataTable.Rows.Count + ");");

                    for (int i = 0; i <= dataTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append("data.setValue( " + i + "," + 0 + "," + "'" + dataTable.Rows[i]["ResourceName"].ToString() + "');");
                        stringBuilder.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 1 + "," + dataTable.Rows[i]["Planned"].ToString() + ") ;");
                        stringBuilder.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 2 + "," + dataTable.Rows[i]["Actual"].ToString() + ") ;");

                        if (Convert.ToDecimal(dataTable.Rows[i]["Planned"]) > Convert.ToDecimal(dataTable.Rows[i]["Actual"]))
                        { color = "green"; }
                        else
                        { color = "red"; }
                    }

                    stringBuilder.Append(" var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
                    stringBuilder.Append(" chart.draw(data, {width: 660, height: 500, title: 'Resource-Performance Graph',");
                    stringBuilder.Append("legend: {position: 'right',alignment: 'start',textStyle: {fontSize: 12}},");
                    stringBuilder.Append("hAxis: {title: 'Resource', titleTextStyle: {color: 'green'},slantedText:true},width:'645',colors: ['DeepSkyBlue','"+color+"'],");

                    stringBuilder.Append("vAxis:{title: 'Effort (Hr)',titleTextStyle: {color: 'green'}}");

                    stringBuilder.Append("}); }");
                    stringBuilder.Append("</script>");
```

how can I set the color for each bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a [Style data role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available)...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'ResourceName');
data.addColumn('number', 'Planned');
data.addColumn('number', 'Actual');

// add style column
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});

// add style color
if (Convert.ToDecimal(dataTable.Rows[i]["Planned"]) > Convert.ToDecimal(dataTable.Rows[i]["Actual"])) {
  stringBuilder.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 3 + ",'color: green;') ;");
} else {
  stringBuilder.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 3 + ",'color: red;') ;");
}
```

Comment: do you mean remove colors: ['DeepSkyBlue','"+color+"'], from hAxis and add this?